# Facebook App Review - Webhooks for pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-webhooks

I have a facebook app which should monitor post, comments on few pages. We are planning to configure webhooks to get notification for feed updates.
I have following queries regarding the same
1. Is it possible to change my Facebook webhook URL for Pages without having FB to review again my application?
2. Can I subscribe to new Pages after the app review is complete? Or do I need to resubmit for review for adding new pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to change my Facebook webhook URL for Pages without having FB to review again my application?

Yes.

> Can I subscribe to new Pages after the app review is complete?

Yes.

> Or do I need to resubmit for review for adding new pages

No, don’t worry. Facebook wants to see in review what *functionality* your app provides, and what it does with the data it accesses; but it is not tied to any specific pages or webhook URLs.